# Wordpress Page Not Displaying Full Width On Mobile - All Items Are Positioned To The Left And There Is A Margin To The Right

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am working on a site

On mobile there is a white margin to the right of the page and the contents of the page are off center.

I have tried implementing CSS to address the issue but it has had no effect so far.

Can anyone help me to narrow down the cause of the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at your site. If you change the CSS class `.col-full` to a maximum width of **100%**, then the problem should be fixed. You can handle it with CSS media queries.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I added:  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .col-full {
    max-width: 100% !important;
}
}

Comment: To the additional CSS but it doesn't appear to have had an effect

Answer (score 1):

Remove `max-width: 80% !important;` from `.col-full` class and you will get rid of the margin on the right.

Comment: Ok thank you. Any tips on where to find the class to edit it? I checked in the CSS for the child theme and also the additional CSS but I can't find i there. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1):

Watching the source code in developer tools I can see that you have a wrapping div that set the width :

```
.col-full {
    max-width: 80% !important;
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you. Any tips on where to find the class to edit it? I checked in the CSS for the child theme and also the additional CSS but I can't find i there. Thanks again for your help

Comment: In the template file just after the google tag script you seems to got a style tag with the rule declared. Probably the `index.php` of your theme file.

Comment: thank you - it wasn't in there but with your help I managed to find it - it was in a file close by! Thanks again